# php determine if a range of dates fall on a weekend

Tags: php, date

I am building a a script to detect whether or not certain dates fall on a weekend every year.

The 25th and 26th are bank holidays, and if they fall on a weekend the next weekday is a substitute for that bank holiday and the remaining weekdays are working days.

Example: if the 25th is a saturday and 26th is a sunday, 27th and 28th will be bank holidays and then 29th, 30th, 31st are working days

if the 25th is a sunday, 26th and 27th, will then be bank holidays and 28th, 29th, 30th will be working days and the 31sy will be a saturday.

Here are my dates:

```
date('25-12-Y');
date('26-12-Y');
date('27-12-Y');
date('28-12-Y');
date('29-12-Y');
date('30-12-Y');
date('31-12-Y');
```

The code i have created is this: (please note the $getyear var is to test different years)

```
function isWeekend($date) {
    return (date('N', strtotime($date)) >= 6);
}
$getyear = 2013;

echo '25 ';
if (isWeekend(date('25-12-'.$getyear))){
   echo 'weekend'; 
} else {
    echo 'bh';
};
echo '<br>';
echo '26 ';
if (isWeekend(date('26-12-'.$getyear ))){
    echo 'weekend';
} else {
    echo 'bh';
};
echo '<br>';
echo '27 ';
if (isWeekend(date('27-12-'.$getyear ))){
    echo 'weekend'; 
} else { 
    echo 'leave';
};
echo '<br>';
echo '28 ';
if (isWeekend(date('28-12-'.$getyear ))){
    echo 'weekend'; 
} else {
    echo 'leave';
};
echo '<br>';
echo '29 ';
if (isWeekend(date('29-12-'.$getyear ))){
    echo 'weekend'; 
} else {
    echo 'leave';
};
echo '<br>';
echo '30 ';
if (isWeekend(date('30-12-'.$getyear ))){
    echo 'weekend'; 
} else {
    echo 'leave';
};
echo '<br>';
echo '31 ';
if (isWeekend(date('31-12-'.$getyear ))){
    echo 'weekend'; 
} else {
    echo 'leave';
};
echo '<br>';
```

I know this is probably not best practice, so i am looking for an alternative way to approach this.

Comment: You can get the "number of the day" from a date in PHP. 0 is Sunday, 1 is Monday and so on. cfr [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dates = array();
$christmas_days = array(25, 26);

$year = 2013;

for ($day = 25; $day <= 31; $day++)
{
    $dates[$day] = date($day . '-12-' . $year);
}



foreach ($dates as $day => $date)
{
    echo $day . ' ';
    if (isWeekend($date))
    {
        echo 'weekend';
        if (in_array($day, $christmas_days))
        {
            $bh_on_weekend++;
        }
    } 
    else
    {
        if ($bh_on_weekend > 0)
        {
            echo 'bh';
            $bh_on_weekend--;
        } 
        else
        {
            if (in_array($day, $christmas_days))
            {
                echo 'bh';
            } 
            else
            {
                echo 'leave';
            }
        }
    }
    echo '<br>';
}

function isWeekend($date)
{
    return (date('N', strtotime($date)) >= 6);
}
```

tried to do on the DRY way to repeat as less as possible. date creation is a bit more dynamical. hope it helps you somehow or give an idea how to make it different.

output for 2021

```
25 weekend
26 weekend
27 bh
28 bh
29 leave
30 leave
31 leave
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! i only get 1 bh when i change the year to 2015. is this the same for you?

Comment: i think i generally missunderstood your question a bit. i didnt notice the fact about 25/26 on weekend.. to get the bh on the next working days. ll try to work it out soon

Comment: ok this is a possible solution just quick implemented. again you need to refactor to keep DRY. hope its the output you expected

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) to abstract all of that logic.

You can then do:

```
$dt = Carbon::create(2013, 12, 25);
$dt->isWeekday(); // bool
```

The Carbon documentation is really good, so I'm sure you will be able to find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This question and answer is ancient by now but I came across this particular issue today and came up with the following function:

```php
if (!function_exists('hasWeekend')) {
    function hasWeekend (\DateTime $dateOne, \DateTime $dateTwo, $weekendDays = ["6", "7"]) {
        $diff = $dateTwo->diff($dateOne)->format('%a');
        $weekend = false;

        while ($diff > 0) {
            $date = $dateTwo->sub(new \DateInterval('P1D'));
            $day = $date->format('N');
            if (in_array($day, $weekendDays)) {
                $weekend = true;
                break;
            }

            $diff--;
        }

        return $weekend;
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```php
$hasWeekend = hasWeekend(new \DateTime('2019-11-25'), new \DateTime('2019-11-26'));
// $hasWeekend = false, Nov 25th is a Monday, Nov 26nd a Tuesday.

$hasWeekend = hasWeekend(new \DateTime('2019-11-27'), new \DateTime('2019-12-2'));
// $hasWeekend = true, December 2nd 2019 is a monday
```

If for whatever reason your weekend days are not Saturday and Sunday, you can change the $weekendDays array to represent the different days.